# Can we write a generic array/slice deduplication in go?

Tags: go, deduplication

Is there a way to write a generic array/slice deduplication in go, for `[]int` we can have something like (from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Remove_duplicate_elements#Go ):

```
func uniq(list []int) []int {
  unique_set := make(map[int] bool, len(list))
  for _, x := range list {
     unique_set[x] = true
   }
  result := make([]int, len(unique_set))
  i := 0
  for x := range unique_set {
     result[i] = x
    i++
  }
  return result
}
```

But is there a way to extend it to support any array? with a signature like:

```
func deduplicate(a []interface{}) []interface{}
```

I know that you can write that function with that signature, but then you can't actually use it on `[]int`, you need to create a `[]interface{}` put everything from the `[]int` into it, pass it to the function then get it back and put it into a `[]interface{}` and go through this new array and put everything in a new `[]int`.

**My question is,** is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not all types in Go support equality, so it cannot work for any type of slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While VonC's answer probably does the closest to what you really want, the only real way to do it in native Go without gen is to define an interface

```
type IDList interface {
   // Returns the id of the element at i
   ID(i int) int

   // Returns the element
   // with the given id
   GetByID(id int) interface{}

   Len() int

   // Adds the element to the list
   Insert(interface{})
}

// Puts the deduplicated list in dst
func Deduplicate(dst, list IDList) {
    intList := make([]int, list.Len())
    for i := range intList {
        intList[i] = list.ID(i)
    }

    uniques := uniq(intList)
    for _,el := range uniques {
        dst.Insert(list.GetByID(el))
    }
}
```

Where `uniq` is the function from your OP.

This is just one possible example, and there are probably much better ones, but in general mapping each element to a unique "==able" ID and either constructing a new list or culling based on the deduplication of the IDs is probably the most intuitive way.

An alternate solution is to take in an `[]IDer` where the `IDer` interface is just `ID() int`. However, that means that **user** code has to create the []IDer list and copy all the elements into that list, which is a bit ugly. It's cleaner for the user to wrap the list as an ID list rather than copy, but it's a similar amount of work either way.

Comment: +1. This seems a more native way to achieve that than what my answer proposes.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have seen that implemented in Go is with the [**clipperhouse/gen**](https://github.com/clipperhouse/gen) project,

> gen is an attempt to bring some generics-like functionality to Go, with some inspiration from C#’s Linq and JavaScript’s underscore libraries

See [this test](https://github.com/clipperhouse/gen/blob/master/test/thing1_gen.go#L54-L64):

```
// Distinct returns a new Thing1s slice whose elements are unique. See: http://clipperhouse.github.io/gen/#Distinct
func (rcv Thing1s) Distinct() (result Thing1s) {
    appended := make(map[Thing1]bool)
    for _, v := range rcv {
        if !appended[v] {
            result = append(result, v)
            appended[v] = true
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**But**, as explained in [clipperhouse.github.io/gen/](http://clipperhouse.github.io/gen/):

> gen **generates code for your types, at development time**, using the command line.
>
> **gen is not an import; the generated source becomes part of your project** and takes no external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something close to this via an interface.  Define an interface, say "DeDupable" requiring a func, say, UniqId() []byte, which you could then use to do the removing of dups. and your uniq func would take a []DeDupable and work on it

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how it will apply to different type of slices like to []int and []string at the same time?