# How to write func for the generic parameter in golang

Tags: arrays, function, go

I am trying to write a function `Map`, so that it can handle all the types of array.

```
// Interface to specify generic type of array.
type Iterable interface {
}

func main() {
    list_1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    list_2 := []uint8{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
    Map(list_1)
    Map(list_2)
}

// This function prints the every element for
// all []types of array.
func Map(list Iterable) {
    for _, value := range list {
        fmt.Print(value)
    }
}
```

But it throws the compile time error.

```
19: cannot range over list (type Iterable)
```

The error is correct because `range` require array, pointer to an array, slice, string, map, or channel permitting receive operations and here type is `Iterable`. I think problem that I am facing is, conversion of the argument type `Iterable` to array type. Please suggest, how could I use my function to handle generic array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Rob Pike mentions in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/9eEBX3vvW_M)

> > Is it possible to express "any map", "any array" or "any slice" in a Go type switch?
>
> No.  **The static types must be exact**.
> The empty interface is really a type, not a wildcard.

You only could iterate over a list of a specific type, like an interface with known functions.
You can see an example with "[Can we write a generic array/slice deduplication in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281328/6309)"

Even using reflection, to pass a slice as an `interface{}` would be, as [this thread shows](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/yQk_g7AjcU8), error-prone (see [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/rs6kfvRD9M)).

---

Update Nov. 2021, 7 years later: [CL 363434](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/exp/+/363434/), for Go 1.18 (Q1 2022) actually introduces functions useful with slices of any type, using [generics](https://go.dev/blog/generics-proposal).

```golang
// Package slices defines various functions useful with slices of any type.
// Unless otherwise specified, these functions all apply to the elements
// of a slice at index 0 <= i < len(s).
package slices
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
// Equal reports whether two slices are equal: the same length and all
// elements equal. If the lengths are different, Equal returns false.
// Otherwise, the elements are compared in index order, and the
// comparison stops at the first unequal pair.
// Floating point NaNs are not considered equal.
func Equal[T comparable](s1, s2 []T) bool {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return false
    }
    for i, v1 := range s1 {
        v2 := s2[i]
        if v1 != v2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Note that [issue 50792](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50792#event-6003920213) and [CL 382834](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/exp/+/382834/) show that:

> We left `constraints` behind in the standard library because we believed it was fundamental to using generics, but in practice that hasn't proven to be the case.
>
> In particular, most code uses `any` or `comparable`.
> If those are the only common constraints, maybe we don't need the package.
> Or if `constraints.Ordered` is the only other commonly used constraint, maybe that should be a predeclared identifier next to `any` and `comparable`.

Hence `import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"` instead of `import "constraints"`.

Comment: would it be possible to know the type and value from the interface argument ? I am still trying to understand it from the shared example.

Comment: @subh.singh not dynamically, which is why it is better to work with an array of a known interface, instead of an `interface{}`.

Comment: @subh.singh at least not without reflection, as bit like in http://play.golang.org/p/jxMFq5UYs1 mentioned in the comments of https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2013/07/15/Golang-Diaries-2.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of Map is some unсomplete. Usual way to declare it would have mapper method.
Your example can be implemented at least this way

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Interface to specify something thet can be mapped.
type Mapable interface {
}


func main() {
    list_1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    list_2 := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    Map(print, list_1)
    Map(print, list_2)
}
func print(value Mapable){
fmt.Print(value)
}

// This function maps the every element for
// all []types of array.
func Map(mapper func(Mapable), list ... Mapable) {
    for _, value := range list {
        mapper(value)
    }
}
```

It [works](https://play.golang.org/p/0_ki7Mv3Qv). Need to say it's a bit of untyped. Because no, Go has not 'generics' in Hindley-Milner sence

Comment: I think if we want to perform some operation on the the elements of the array then we have to go with reflection. In the current example we are printing the value, not doing any operation on the elements.

Comment: the usage of interface is the key here. you can directly print without Map func. thank you @Uvelichitel